# Unable to see and scroll the html view of ionic modal when keyboard appear

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using ionic modal in ionic project. the modal is appearing on page clearly, but when I am trying to enter any text into any textbox the keyboard is appearing on page.

Once the keyboard appeared, I am unable to see the html of modal and also unable to scroll modal.
 kindly refer the screenshot.

[image: please see the attached image]

Thank you.

Comment: I suspect it's a `float` or `position:absolute` problem. Try giving a `overflow:hidden` to the container and a `height:100%`

Comment: @ Jonathan Argentiero by giving height:100% , The height is increasing of modal but still I am unable to see the html, same issue like image attached, overflow: hidden is already there.

Comment: I have tried only modal form in another blank application and facing same issue. I have not changed any css and js file, by default I am facing this issue. I was looking by inspect elements and found -- when keyboard is appearing on screen the "ion-content" tag getting inline css i.e. height:22.8125px.

Comment: it's not a clean solution, give that `ion-content` a `height: 100% !important`. Without a fiddle is difficult to find the problem.

Comment: ion-content getting inline css, If I write css for ion-content its overwriting it. this problem is only occurring on device not on browser, how can I fiddle it ?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Did you solve it? I tried setting `height: 100%!important` to `ion-content` but this only works one time. If i open up the keyboard again, I face the same problem.

Comment: sorry for late response, did't get permanent  solution for this but I had written some custom css for it. and resolved, not 100%. you can also try. try this  `@media (min-width: 680px) {
    .modal {
        top: 0;
        height: 70%;
    }
    body.keyboard-open .modal {
        height: 90%;
    }body.keyboard-open .modal .scroll {
        overflow-y: scroll !important;
    }
}

.overflow-scroll.keyboard-up:not(.keyboard-up-confirm) {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100% !important;
    top: 0;
}`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Working great (except for the animation) - but I really appreciate that fix! Saved me a lot of time.

Comment: @dominik as you tried this and its working, I am answering my own question. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Waited for long time and did't get any answer, So I have written some css to fix this issue, This is working in my project as well as [dominik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1396774/dominik)
also tried this. `see the comment by him`

```
    @media(min-width: 680px){
    .modal{ top: 0; height: 70%; }
    body.keyboard-open.modal{ height: 90%; }
    body.keyboard-open.modal.scroll{ overflow-y: scroll !important; }
}
.overflow-scroll.keyboard-up:not(.keyboard-up-confirm){
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100% !important;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: please also put html so it more describe classes.

Answer (score 1):

Had to come up with this fix. it worked for me, so give it a try: Put the code in your *app.run*

**NOTE:** this issue is normally caused when you set  *android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"* in your AndroidManifest.xml

*Make sure jquery is included in your app.*

```
 window.addEventListener('native.keyboardshow', keyboardShowHandler);
  window.addEventListener('native.keyboardhide', keyboardHideHandler);

  function keyboardShowHandler(e){ 
  setTimeout(function() { 
    var originalHeight =  window.innerHeight-30; 
    var newHeight = originalHeight - e.keyboardHeight;
      $('ion-modal-view ion-content').css("height", newHeight); 
  }, 0);
    }

function keyboardHideHandler(e){ 
  setTimeout(function() { 
    var newHeight = '100%';
      $('ion-modal-view ion-content').css("height", newHeight); 
  }, 0);
 }
```